# Getting the percent of a number

Tags: sql-server

I think it is some funky rounding issue going on here, but I don't know how the inner sql works. So maybe someone can help.

```
   SELECT COUNT(Id) TotalReferrals,
   SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed1_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NHSCommNeed1Total, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed2_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NHSCommNeed2Total,
   SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed3_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
   NHSCommNeed3Total
   INTO #Totals
   FROM DDS.Referrals
```

Gives me the following result set

```
TotalReferrals  NHSCommNeed1Total   NHSCommNeed2Total   NHSCommNeed3Total
1008            1008                508                 508
```

Then when I do this

```
SELECT 
   SUM((NHSCommNeed1Total / TotalReferrals) * 100) NHSCommNeed1Percent, 
   SUM((NHSCommNeed2Total / TotalReferrals) * 100) NHSCommNeed2Percent,
   SUM((NHSCommNeed3Total / TotalReferrals) * 100) NHSCommNeed3Percent
FROM #Totals
```

I get this?

```
NHSCommNeed1Percent NHSCommNeed2Percent NHSCommNeed3Percent
100                 0                   0
```

Can someone explain what is going on and how do I fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `NHSCommNeed1Total / (TotalReferrals` is calculated as integer, therefore it ends up to 0. To enforce making it decimal or double just multiply it with `1.0`:

```
SELECT 
   SUM((NHSCommNeed1Total / (TotalReferrals * 1.0)) * 100) NHSCommNeed1Percent, 
   SUM((NHSCommNeed2Total / (TotalReferrals * 1.0)) * 100) NHSCommNeed2Percent,
   SUM((NHSCommNeed3Total / (TotalReferrals * 1.0)) * 100) AS NHSCommNeed3Percent
FROM #Totals
```

---

Yes sure, no need for two statements, you can use `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(Id) TotalReferrals,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed1_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) NHSCommNeed1Total, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed2_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) NHSCommNeed2Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed3_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) 
       NHSCommNeed3Total
       FROM DDS.Referrals
)
INSERT INTO SomeOtherTable(NHSCommNeed1Total,NHSCommNeed2Total ,NHSCommNeed3Total)
SELECT
  SUM((NHSCommNeed1Total / (TotalReferrals * 1.0)) * 100) AS NHSCommNeed1Percent, 
  SUM((NHSCommNeed2Total / (TotalReferrals * 1.0)) * 100) NHSCommNeed2Percent,
  SUM((NHSCommNeed3Total / (TotalReferrals * 1.0)) * 100) AS NHSCommNeed3Percent
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I could merge both statements, so I don't have to insert into #Totals and just query DDS.Referrals

Comment: Instead of inserting them, wrap the first query with another select, and make your aggregation there. @BenDonnelly

Comment: alternatively they can fix it in the `CASE` expression  with `THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 0):

If you want an all in one statement this should work

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed1_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(Id)  as NHSCommNeed1Percent, 
SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed2_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(Id)  as NHSCommNeed2Percent,
SUM(CASE WHEN NHSCommunicationNeed3_Id IS NOT NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(Id)  as NHSCommNeed3Percent
FROM DDS.Referrals
```